# SQL select statement, calculating columns based on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I'm trying to sum up individual prices and use logic for a discount.

```
SELECT O.OrderID, 
    if(C.IsClubMember & OrderNumber % 10 = 0, 0.5 * Sum(I.ItemPrice), Sum(I.ItemPrice)) as Price, 
    0.07*Price as Tax, Price + Tax as Total
FROM Orders as O JOIN ItemPriceView as I 
    ON O.OrderID = I.OrderID JOIN Customer as C 
    ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
GROUP BY OrderID
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Price' in 'field list'
```

What is the right way to write my query?

Comment: You can't reuse aliases in the `select` clause.

Comment: So do I need to just copy paste the entire logical clause into each part of the select? Do I need to make an intermediate view to hold the price, then do tax & total later?

Comment: You can just copy/paste the logic in the select clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a sub-query to calculate the price, then calculate tax and total in the outer query.

This should work:

```
SELECT OrderID, Price, 0.07*Price as Tax, 1.07*Price as Total
FROM
(
SELECT O.OrderID as OrderID, 
    if(C.IsClubMember & OrderNumber % 10 = 0, 0.5 * Sum(I.ItemPrice),Sum(I.ItemPrice)) as Price
FROM Orders as O JOIN ItemPriceView as I 
    ON O.OrderID = I.OrderID JOIN Customer as C 
    ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
GROUP BY OrderID
) as sub_query
```